# Pfsense OpenVPN Site to Site Routing issues

Tags: routing, openvpn, pfsense, site-to-site-vpn

I know this question has been asked a plethora of times before and I have looked over probably 100 different answers and still can't seem to get this to work.

I'm trying to create a very simple site to site openvpn connection. I have the connection setup and working between the two locations however I cannot get the routing setup to communicate between the devices on the different networks.

## Site A (Main): 192.168.1.0/24

[image]

## Site B: 192.168.2.0/24

[image]

## VPN Tunnel: 10.1.10.0/24

[image]

Trace Route fails after first attempt so the it looks like the route isn't working at all.

Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: Check your firewall rules. It's most likely you simply haven't passed the traffic through. The relevant rules can be found under Firewall->Rules and then on the OpenVPN "pseudo"-interface.

Comment: I have an allow all rule on both sides under the OpenVPN tab.

Comment: Well, it should work. So just a few ideas for what you might check: Have you got IPsec set up with the same IPs that might be interfering with OpenVPN? Try deleting the "route" statement from the OpenVPN config and just going with the "remote site" net. Have you assigned the OpenVPN interfaces to pfSense interfaces? If so you need to set your firewall rules there. Also, it might be that something is out of sync with the webui. Rebooting both sides certainly won't work. Failing that, post your config.xml (you can get it via the Backup feature), redacting out any sensitive info including keys.

Answer (score 0):

Answer comes in form of a question. Where is your NAT rule which is going to translate outbound traffic? You should have outbound NAT on the site of your server set like this:

Interface: the one you are using for your tunnel

Protocol: any

Source: network from other site

Destination: any

And under translation

Adress: interface address

You need outbound NAT because otherwise you aren't able to use tunnel. Simply because your router don't know the route to the network on the other site. But if you translate source address to your tunnel interface address then it will be able to respond.

Comment: The question is 4 years old now. In the lastest pfsense 2.4.3 do I still need to define the NAT outbound rules for site to site configuration ? I am facing issues like it's not able to connect

Answer (score -1):

On both Site A and Site B For your VPN Tunnel instead of using 10.1.10.0/24  try 10.1.10.0/30

I believe what you are doing should work, and I think this may be a bug in pfSense - I can't get the way you are doing it to work either, however it works from if I use /30...

Comment: Thanks ill give that a try! Its been over a year since ive worked on this project lol. Ill have to re-orient myself.

Answer (score -1):

For site2site vpn i preferred IPSEC.
Anyway try to follow this instructions (officials): https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/OpenVPN_Site_To_Site

I implemented it in the past and work fine.